# Magento 2, addAttributeToSelect not working with product collection?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, collection, json, select

I am applying these fillers:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
```

but every time getting full record as comes form:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

[{"entity_id":"101","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-XS-White","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"},{"entity_id":"102","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-XS-Yellow","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"},{"entity_id":"103","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-S-Green","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"},{"entity_id":"104","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-S-White","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"},{"entity_id":"105","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-S-Yellow","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"},{"entity_id":"106","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-M-Green","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"},{"entity_id":"107","attribute_set_id":"9","type_id":"simple","sku":"MH04-M-White","has_options":"0","required_options":"0","created_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50","updated_at":"2018-10-08 07:35:50"}]
```

I am getting collection using class as:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
```

and

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
    $collection->setPageSize(50)->setCurPage($page);
    return json_encode($collection->getData());

}
```

Comment: It's working? @AjwadTaqvi

Comment: how do you get the collection?

Comment: I updated Question.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating my custom collection as:

```
public function getProductCollection()//In block
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
    $collection->setPageSize(50)->setCurPage($page);
    return $collection;
}


$cusCollection = array(); //Custom Collection for retriving required data in controller 
    $i=0;
    $productCollection = $this->product->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        $cusCollection['items'][$i]['itemID'] = $product->getId();
        $id = $product->getId();
        $_productStock = $this->order->getStockItem($id);
        $productQty = $_productStock->getQty();
        $cusCollection['items'][$i]['name '] = $product->getName().' '.$productQty; 
        $cusCollection['items'][$i]['sku '] = $product->getSku();
        $i++;
}
       echo json_encode($cusCollection);
```

Comment: It's product collection or ordered product collection?

Comment: It is product collection.

Comment: Please added here which class you inject in construct for $this->order.

Comment: By this I am calling my block class function in controller. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: It's not understandable. That's why I told to upload whole answer. So, it will helpful for other user also.

Comment: check the updated answer please

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name','sku']);
```

OR

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
```

---

OR

```
protected $_productCollection;

public function __construct(
...........
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,
...........
) {
    ...........
    $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
    ...........
}
```

and

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(['name','sku']);
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
    $collection->setPageSize(50)->setCurPage($page);
    return json_encode($collection->getData());
}
```

Comment: No change occured, if apply these filters as in updated question, data appears complete still. where as i need only Name, SKU, Qty.
I deleted generated folder and cache cleared.

Comment: Yes. I already mention in my answer that. $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

Comment: [] getting empty array with updated solution :d

Comment: Check updated answer now.

Comment: undefined method, getCollection()
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor::getCollection() 
Removed generation, cache cleared, still same